# Knockoutjs - With bindings and state

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm having an issue with component binding and state.

This is my html template:

```
<div class="ts-panel content">
<!--ko with: states.createState-->
<div data-bind="component: 'customer-create'">Testing CreateState</div>
<!--/ko-->
<!--ko with: states.lookupState-->
<div data-bind="component: 'customer-search'">Testing LookupState</div>
<!--/ko-->
</div>
```

This is my javascript

```
var myDataModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.states = {};
    self.states.createState = ko.observable(true);
    self.states.lookupState = ko.observable(false);
    self.states.currentState = ko.observable(self.states.createState);
    self.states.changeState = function (state) {
    var currentState = self.states.currentState();
        currentState(false);
        self.states.currentState(state);
        state(true);
    }
};
return myDataModel;
```

I'm using another script to control which state I'm in by binding click events to certain buttons.

The problem I'm running into is that when I change the current state, the component bindings reset the state of the component.  Eg. on the customer-create component, I fill out a form, then change to the lookupState, then change back to the createState, the form values are gone.

I think this is happening because the components are getting wiped out and recreated every time.

I also think that one solution to this is to store everything at the root level (i.e. the component that stores the states) and pass that all down when required to the individual components.  However, I'd really like to keep the component-specific information inside those components.

Is there a way to store the state of the components or maybe store the components in a variable and bind to it that way?

Comment: Instead of the containerless syntax (`<!--ko`), you could use a `<div data-bind="visible: states.createState">` wrapper. This only hides and shows the `div` based on the boolean. You could also try adding that to the `data-bind="component: 'customer-create', visible: states.createState"` itself.

Comment: @adiga I did not know about the visible binding.  If you want to write up some short and sweet, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.  That did exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: Could you check if `<div data-bind="component: 'customer-create' , visible: states.createState"` works? It should. That way you don't have to add the wrapper `div `and mess up any CSS selectors

Comment: Yep, that appears to work just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentations](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html#parameters):

> If the expression you supply involves any observable values, the expression will be re-evaluated whenever any of those observables change. The descendant elements will be cleared out, and a new copy of the markup will be added to your document and bound in the context of the new value.

The behaviour is same for the [`if`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) binding as well. You could use the [`visible`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html) binding for this. This just hides and shows the `div` without actually removing it from the DOM. There is no containerless control flow syntax for `visible`. So, you'd have to add it to the `div`

```
<div data-bind="component:'customer-create', visible: states.createState">Testing CreateState</div>
```